# How to split a string to an array of characters in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am trying to convert a string, for example, "how are you doing?" into an array without any comma space or any punctuation, which is like {'h','o','w','a','r','e','y','o','u','d','o','i','n','g'}
This is the function I wrote below, but it does not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
char split(string str){
        char array[80];
        for (int i=0; i<str.length();i++){
                if (str[i]==","||str[i]=="."||str[i]==" ")
                        delete str[i];
                else
                        array[i]=str.substr(i,1);
        }
        return (array[80]);
}
```

Comment: Expand on "does not work".

Comment: A string already *is* an array of characters.

Comment: so what should I change to make it work?

Comment: Main error is "" around "," etc. and use `str[i]` instead of `str.substr(i,i+1)` to get a `char.`

Comment: @user783920, I don't think there really *is* one main error. I count around 10 separate ones.

Comment: you're returning array[80], which is just one char. is that what you want? maybe return array.

Comment: @chris, it would have at least compiled before the edit.

Comment: What are you hoping that `delete str[i]` will achieve ?

Comment: @user3444127 `array` resides on stack and must not be returned. Not sure why the return type is `char`. I feel it should be `char*` on seeing what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some notes on your code:

1. `<cstring>` (i.e. `<string.h>`) is useless, since you don't use anything from the `<cstring>` header in your code.
2. Since `string` is an input read-only parameter, you can pass it by `const &`.
3. Since you want an array of chars, you can either return a `vector<char>` (or even a `string`...).

To solve your problem, you can simply iterate through the characters of the input string, and if they are alphabetical and numeric characters (i.e. no space, no comma, etc.), you can add them to the output result vector of chars.

You may want to consider the following sample commented code:

```
#include <ctype.h>      // For isalnum()
#include <iostream>     // For console output
#include <string>       // For std::string
#include <vector>       // For std::vector
using namespace std;

vector<char> split(const string& str)
{
    vector<char> result;

    // For each character in the string
    for (char ch : str)
    {
        // Copy only alphabetical characters and numeric digits
        if (isalnum(ch))
        {
            result.push_back(ch);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    vector<char> result = split("How are you doing?");
    cout << "{ ";
    for (char ch : result)
    {
        cout << "'" << ch << "' "; 
    }
    cout << "}" << endl;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> { 'H' 'o' 'w' 'a' 'r' 'e' 'y' 'o' 'u' 'd' 'o' 'i' 'n' 'g' }
> ```

---

If you like a more *"functional"* style, you can use the `std::copy_if()` algorithm, with some code like this:

```
#include <algorithm> // For std::copy_if()
#include <iterator>  // For std::back_inserter

....
const string str = "How are you doing?";
vector<char> result;
copy_if(
    str.begin(), str.end(),                // copy source
    back_inserter(result),                 // copy destination
    [](char ch) { return isalnum(ch); }    // when to copy the character
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is very helpful, but the problem is that I did not get that far yet in my class. I think the professor of my class only allows us to use <string> <iostream> and some simple libraries. But I will definitely write this one down for my future study!

Answer (score 0):

You are reinventing the wheel

`std::string` has [methods to help you](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/)

for example

```
size_t found = str.find_last_of(".");
str.replace(found,1," ");
```

Comment: Looks more like a simple `copy_if`.

Comment: Yes, a copy_if is just around the corner :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also use simple iteration using `char*` to go through the string and pick out what you need.

I am not sure what's the reason for returning `array[80]` frm `split` but that is not relevant to your question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

char split(std::string str)
{
   char array[80];
   char const* cp = str.c_str();
   int i = 0;
   for (; *cp; ++cp )
   {
      if ( isalnum(*cp) )
      {
         array[i++] = *cp;
      }
   }
   array[i] = '\0';

   cp = array;
   for (; *cp; ++cp )
   {
      std::cout << "'" << *cp << "' ";
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;

   return (array[80]);
}

int main()
{
   split("What are you having for lunch today?");
}
```

Output:

```
'W' 'h' 'a' 't' 'a' 'r' 'e' 'y' 'o' 'u' 'h' 'a' 'v' 'i' 'n' 'g' 'f' 'o' 'r' 'l' 'u' 'n' 'c' 'h' 't' 'o' 'd' 'a' 'y'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution:

I change return type to string, If you insist you can take the `c_str()` of return value to `const char*`

string is already like vector of characters.

```
string split(string str)
{
    size_t i=0;
    while (string::npos != (i=str.find_first_of(",. ",i))){
        str.erase(i,1);
    }
    return str;
}
```

You use it like this:

```
string s = split("bla bla bla");
```

if you want the pointer:

```
cout<<s.c_str()<<endl;
```